# How to set an input value with jquery?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

i have this code, i want when input field #amount is add, jquery will get the value, multiply it with 0.20 and add the value to #agentfee. The value of #agentfee will be used to insert value in sql table using php code. I dont know why my code is not working

```
HTML
<label for="amount">Rent Amount</label>
    <input type="number" id="amount" name="amount" placeholder="500,000">
<label for="agentfee">Agent fee N</label>
    <input type="Number" id="agentfee" name="agentfee" value="" readonly><br>


JS
$('#amount').change(function() { 
    
    var inputValue = $("#amount").val();
    agentFee = inputValue * 0.20;
    $('#agentfee').val=('agentFee');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

As @Calvin pointed out already you need to change your `$('#agentfee').val()` line:

```js
$('#amount').on("input",function() { 

var inputValue = $("#amount").val();
agentFee = inputValue * 0.20;
$('#agentfee').val(agentFee.toFixed(2));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
<label for="amount">Rent Amount</label>
<input type="number" id="amount" name="amount" placeholder="500,000">
<label for="agentfee">Agent fee N</label>
<input type="Number" id="agentfee" name="agentfee" value="" readonly><br>
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the ticks around agentFee, or the equals. It should be

```
$('#agentfee').val(agentFee);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :
$('#amount').change(function() {

```
var inputValue = $("#amount").val();
agentFee = inputValue * 0.20;
$('#agentfee').val('agentFee');
});
```

i hope it was useful

Answer (score 0):

Your

```
$('#agentfee').val=('agentFee');
```

overrides the `val` function of `$('#agentfee')` with the text of `agentFee`. Instead, you wanted to call `val` and pass a value, like `$('#agentfee').val(yourvalue);`. This is a simplified solution (I have changed the event from `change` to `input` to make sure the input is more responsive. If you strongly prefer the `change` event, then let me know)

```js
$('#amount').on('input', function() { 
    $('#agentfee').val($("#amount").val() * 0.20);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label for="amount">Rent Amount</label>
    <input type="number" id="amount" name="amount" placeholder="500,000">
<label for="agentfee">Agent fee N</label>
    <input type="Number" id="agentfee" name="agentfee" value="" readonly><br>
```